# Построение графика в реальном времени в python

Tags: python, график

Здравствуйте! Написал код, который строит модель обратного маятника:

```
from math import *
import pygame
import numpy as np

dt = 0.01
g = 9.81
l = 1.0
m = 1.0

global k1, k2, k3
k1 = 5000 #пропорциональный коэффициент
k2 = 100 #дифференциальный коэффициент
k3 = 1 #интегральный коэффициент

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
size = (width, height) = (1200, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)


class Pendulum:
    def __init__(self, x0, y0, phi0):
        self.phi0 = phi0
        self.phi = phi0
        self.velocity = 0
        self.x0 = x0
        self.y0 = y0
        self.x0_vel = 0
        self.x = x0 + 250.0 * sin(phi0)
        self.y = y0 + 250.0 * cos(phi0)

        self.t = dt
        self.t = np.arange(0, 30, 0.01)

    def move(self, control):
        self.phi = atan2(self.x - self.x0, self.y - self.y0) #arctg(y/x)
        d_velocity = -g * sin(self.phi) * dt / l
        self.velocity += d_velocity
        d_phi = dt * self.velocity
        self.phi += d_phi
        self.x = self.x0 + 250.0 * sin(self.phi)
        self.y = self.y0 + 250.0 * cos(self.phi)

        d_x0_vel = dt * control
        self.x0_vel += d_x0_vel
        dx0 = dt * self.x0_vel
        self.x0 += dx0

        if self.x0 > 1200 or self.x0 < 0:
            self.x0 -= dx0

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), [int(self.x0), int(self.y0)], 5)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), [self.x0, self.y0], [self.x, self.y], 2)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), [int(self.x), int(self.y)], 10)
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (0, 0, 0), [0, self.y0], [1200, self.y0], 3)


class PID:
    def __init__(self, k1, k2, k3, pendulum):
        self.k1 = k1
        self.k2 = k2
        self.k3 = k3
        self.p = pendulum
        self.error = pi - self.p.phi
        self.derivative = 0
        self.integral = 0

    def update(self):
        self.k1 = k1
        self.k2 = k2
        self.k3 = k3

        tmp = self.error
        self.error = copysign(1, p.phi) * (pi - abs(self.p.phi)) + (self.p.x0 - 600) / 10000
        diff = self.error - tmp
        self.derivative = diff / dt
        self.integral += tmp

    # print self.error
    def output(self):
        return self.k1 * self.error + self.k2 * self.derivative + self.k3 * self.integral


def pid_tune(pid):
    global k1, k2, k3
    # new_pend = Pendulum(pend.x0, pend.y0, pend.phi)
    # new_pid = PID(pid.k1, pid.k2, pid.k3, new_pend)
    # new_pid.derivative = pid.derivative
    # new_pid.integral = pid.integral
    n_params = 3
    init_params = [pid.k1, pid.k2, pid.k3]
    params = [0.0 for i in range(n_params)]

    for i in range(n_params):
        params[i] = init_params[i]


def draw_text():
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
    label1 = myfont.render("Пропорциональный коэффициент: %d" % k1, 1, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label1, (100, 500))
    label2 = myfont.render("Дифференциальный коэффициент: %d" % k2, 1, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label2, (100, 520))
    label3 = myfont.render("Интегральный коэффициент: %.1f" % k3, 1, (255, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label3, (100, 540))


def make_buttons(k1, k2, k3, pid):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), [320, 500, 90, 15]) #k1+
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), [420, 500, 90, 15]) #k1-
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), [320, 520, 90, 15]) #k2+
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), [420, 520, 90, 15]) #k2-
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), [320, 540, 90, 15]) #k3+
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), [420, 540, 90, 15]) #k3-

    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
    label1 = myfont.render("Повысить", 1, (255, 255, 255))
    label2 = myfont.render("Понизить", 1, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(label1, (320, 500))
    screen.blit(label2, (420, 500))
    screen.blit(label1, (320, 520))
    screen.blit(label2, (420, 520))
    screen.blit(label1, (320, 540))
    screen.blit(label2, (420, 540))

    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        (pos1, pos2) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if 320 <= pos1 <= 410 and 500 <= pos2 <= 515:
            k1 += 10
        elif 420 <= pos1 <= 490 and 500 <= pos2 <= 515:
            k1 -= 10
        elif 320 <= pos1 <= 410 and 520 <= pos2 <= 535:
            k2 += 1
        elif 420 <= pos1 <= 490 and 520 <= pos2 <= 535:
            k2 -= 1
        elif 320 <= pos1 <= 410 and 540 <= pos2 <= 555:
            k3 += 0.1
        elif 420 <= pos1 <= 490 and 540 <= pos2 <= 555:
            k3 -= 0.1
        elif 600 <= pos1 <= 720 and 500 <= pos2 <= 555:
            pid_tune(pid)

    return k1, k2, k3


p = Pendulum(600, 300, pi - pi / 10)
pid = PID(k1, k2, k3, p)
while 1:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    pid.update()
    p.move(pid.output())
    p.draw()
    draw_text()
    (k1, k2, k3) = make_buttons(k1, k2, k3, pid)

    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Нужно построить 2 анимированных графика: phi от t и velocity от t

Как построить график в реальном времени, который будет строиться в зависимости от полученных phi и velocity во время балансирования обратного маятника?

ПОМОГИТЕ, ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, ХОТЬ КТО-НИБУДЬ!!!